# Struts2 Context handling

Tags: hibernate, session, struts2

I need some help in session management for database in hibernate. Working with struts2 and hibernate. I have gone through simple apps. Now I want my Database connection in Startup so that I don't need to make connection overhead everytime I request.
In short How to configure my hibernate session in ServletContextListener. or is there any other way??
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to proceed would be to use some connection pool so the database connections are started at the beginning and they are managed to acquire new ones or keep a number of them open by configuration.
There are many options, ones of the most extended are [DBCP](http://jakarta.apache.org/commons/dbcp/) or [C3P0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0).